# Swim from Dubrovnik to Lokrum

Tags: croatia, swimming

I'd like to take a swim from Dubrovnik to the island of Lokrum and back. Are there any non-obvious factors (strong currents? marine animals? local police? Game of Thrones fans?) that would prevent me from doing so?

What would be the recommended starting / landing points?